# optimizing the product add action

Tags: cakephp

I have an `add` action form `ProductsController` which has many prices depending on the size. I am trying to save the product first and then within foreach loop the prices.

Some how `saveAll` or `saveAssociated` did not work.

```
public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Product->create();
            $product = $this->Product->save($this->request->data);

            if (!empty($product)) {
                $product_id = $this->Product->getInsertID();
                $prices = $this->request->data['Product']['price'];

                foreach ($prices as $price) {
                    $price['product_id'] = $product_id;
                    $this->Product->Price->save($price);
                     $this->Product->Price->id = false;
                }

                $this->Session->setFlash('The product has been saved.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add the product.');
            }
        }
    }
```

The models are look like

```
class Product extends AppModel {        
   ...
   public $hasMany = array(
      'Price' => array(
              'className' => 'Price',           
                 )
   );


class Price extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Product' => array(
            'className' => 'Product',
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id', 
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: `$product_id = $this->Product->getInsertID();`? Its just `$product_id = $this->Product->id`!

Comment: No need to ask the same question twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `saveAssociated()` as per [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto)

But your view should look something like this:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Product', array('action' => 'add'));
    echo $this->Form->input('Product.name', array('label' => 'Name'));
    echo $this->Form->input('Product.description', array('label' => 'Description'));

    echo $this->Form->input('Price.0.amount', array('label' => 'Amount'));
    echo $this->Form->input('Price.0.price', array('label' => 'Price'));
echo $this->Form->end('Add');
```